# how to store a text in one activity and retrieve it in another activity.?

Tags: android

I have created an app for alarm service..such that a person can set a alarm to a specific time and the alarm will pop up as a notification..Now i want to create that alarm service app to a task reminder app such a way that at the time of creating or setting the task , user input the message in the edit text and save it and then when the alarm pops up , and if the user taps the notification , a new activity comes up and the message that he typed earlier is printed in front of him..(i mean the message is show as a text view to him) So Please tell me how could i do that using shared preferences..

In simple way just tell how could a load the stored string from the activity where the string was created and save with the help of a button and to load that same string and pass it in a text view to some other activity..

Comment: You can use shared preferences or application variables. Best solution is to pass the value to the second activity

Comment: You can pass the necessary data with Alarm intent itself.

Comment: Try using putExtra method. Pass the string using putExtra to the next activity. and show it using getExtra in the next activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared-preferences to store data in one activity. and these data will be available in any activity with in same application.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

example is available at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Good Luck.......

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to do all your preference tasks in your Application Utils.clas

// Declaration

```
public static String KEY = "SESSION";
```

// Method declaration :

```
public static void saveUserName(String userid, Context context) {
    Editor editor = context
            .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("username", userid);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getUserName(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences savedSession = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY,
            Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return savedSession.getString("username", "");
}
```

// You can save the values in preference by calling the below :

```
Utils.saveUserName("12345",YourActivity.this);
```

// Finally you can retrieve the stored value by calling this code snippet :

```
String myUserName = Utils.getUserName(YourActivity.this);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences.

Using `setSetting`, you can set the text at caller class. Similarly, you can get the text which was set in the caller class using `getSetting` in the called class.

**Method to set the Preference**-

```
public void setSetting(String key, String value) {

if(getActivity() != null)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("UserPref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

**Method to get the preference**-

```
public String getSetting(String key, String def) {

try
{
SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("UserPref", 0);
return settings.getString(key, def);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return "";
}
```

Here,

```
public abstract SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)
```

Retrieve and hold the contents of the preferences file 'name', returning a SharedPreferences through which you can retrieve and modify its values. Only one instance of the SharedPreferences object is returned to any callers for the same name, meaning they will see each other's edits as soon as they are made.

More on [Android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).